# Vim substitutes empty string when exception is thrown inside sub-replace expression

Tags: vim

**Update**

Submitted the [issue](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/4161), has been fixed in [Vim 8.1.1061](https://github.com/vim/vim/releases/tag/v8.1.1061).

---

I'm writing a short script for adding delay to .srt files in Vim.

The core functionality could practically be a one-liner substitute command searching for timecodes and referring to a helper function which converts its argument to millisecs, do the math, then converts the result back to timecode format.

However, I'd like to do an additional check - if any of the new values are negative, then throw an exception, which I'd like to handle. Given a well-formed subtitle file with the timecode lines in the right order, we can assume the exception will be thrown right at the very first match, if at all, so no state change to worry about - at least that's what I thought.

```vim
fun! s:DelayTimecodes(delay)
    try
        let saved_view = winsaveview()
        let timecode = '\v\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{3}'
        exe 'keepjumps keeppatterns %s/' . timecode . '/'
                    \ . '\=s:DelayedTimecode(submatch(0), a:delay)/g'    
    catch 'illegal timecode value'
        redraw | echo 'Cannot apply: the given delay time would result'
                    \ . ' in negative timecode value(s)'
    finally
        call winrestview(saved_view)
    endtry
endfun
```

But when an exception is thrown by `DelayedTimecode` inside the `\=` expression, the matches on the first matching line are still replaced, by an empty string. As a temporary solution, I've written a loop, doing the substitution line by line, creating the whole delayed line first (that might throw an exception), and passing that to the substitute command. This works fine, but feels ridiculously over-engineered.

What is the reason behind this? Is there any way to circumvent this behavior, without undoing the substitution command & clearing the history, which is kinda messy?

Comment: I can reproduce that. Don't know if it is a bug, at least it is a surprising behavior. You might want to open an issue at the [Vim Github repo](https://github.com/vim/vim).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exceptions don't work well with [`sub-replace-expression`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#sub-replace-expression). You could raise an issue at Vim's [bug tracker](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues), or directly discuss this on the [vim_dev mailing list](https://www.vim.org/community.php), but chances are this is classified as implementation-specific behavior, and put on the back burner.

The easiest workaround would be to just return the original match (`submatch(0)`) instead of throwing the exception (making the `:substitute` a no-op), and setting an internal flag that makes the expression do the same for each following invocation of the expression within the `:substitute`. Then, afterwards, you can check that flag and print the error message, just as you're now doing in `:catch`.

If you want to avoid any buffer modification (also marking it as modified), you'd have to `:call search()` to locate the first timecode instance, extract it (`getline()`, `matchstr()`), and do the check before the actual `:substitute`.

Comment: I prefer the second workaround solution - besides the buffer modification, running the search on a typical .srt file is not really instantaneous on an average machine (i.e., my laptop), even when the match is simply returned in the expression then.